# Send csv with airflow

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

Hi i'm trying to send a file with airflow (composer) csv stored in gcp storage but i can't attach it.
I get the error "No such file or directory: 'gs://bucket-test/test.csv'"

the mail is sent correctly if I do not attach a file.

another question is: can I create a csv without saving it to storage? and send it directly

```
output_file = 'gs://bucket-test/test.csv'

email_summary = email_operator.EmailOperator(
    task_id='email_summary',
    to=['test@gmail.com'],
    subject='Sample email',
    html_content="""
    test_01. 
    """,
    files=[output_file])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

airflow cannot directly access the storage bucket, so the file must first be downloaded to the local file system

```
download_file = GCSToLocalFilesystemOperator(
    task_id="download_file",
    object_name='test.csv',
    bucket='bucket-test',
    filename='/home/airflow/gcs/data/test.csv',
)
```